# Genfu nuget library generating duplicate data.I want Id property to be unique.How can this be achieved?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nuget-package

```
List<Person> person = A.ListOf<Person>(20);
```

I'm performing mocking. For that i'm using Genfu nuget library to generate fake data for various properties. It does populate fake data but generates some duplicate data which I don't want.

I want the Id & Email property to be unique. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution for it. This will refrain it from providing duplicate values for Id property.

```
var i = 0;
person = A.ListOf<Person>(20);
person.ForEach(x =>
{
    i++;
    x.Id = i;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that's not currently possible.

See the tracking [issue](https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu/issues/50) for more details.

You can play around with the fill to enforce unique on your own for certain members.

```
    A.Configure<Person>()
            .Fill(x => x.Id, x => myOwnWayToEnforceUniqueness());
```

Of course that kills the point of using a mocking library but it can be helpful if unique does not matter for the rest of the fields.